# applicability of mutli threading to a specific scenario in a java program

Tags: java, multithreading

I am confused about the applicability of multi threading in general...

I am creating an application which executes some code which has been saved in xml format. The work is to use apache http client and retrieve some data from websites...More than 1 website can be visited by one block of code in xml...

Now I want that if 2 users have created their own respective codes and saved them in XML, then each user's 'job' (ie block of code in xml format) runs in a separate thread.

I have with me code to execute one user's code...Now I want that multiple persons' code can be run in parallel. But I have some doubts--

(1) The Apache HTTP client provides a way of multithreaded communication, currently I am simply using the default HTTP client- this same client can be made to visit multiple websites, one after the other- as per code block in xml. Am I correct in thinking that I do not need to change my code so that it uses the recommended multithreaded communication?

(2) I am thinking of creating a servlet that when invoked, executes one block of xml code. So to execute 2 blocks of code as given by 2 different users, I will have to invoke this servlet twice. I am going to deploy this application using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, so what I am confused about is, do I need to use multi threading at all in my program? Can I not simply invoke the existing code (which is used to execute one block of code at a time) from the servlet? And I do want to keep processing of the different blocks of XML code separate from each other, so I dont think I should use multi threading here.. Am I correct in my assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running it one after the other as per your 1st option will not be considered 'concurrent' .

Coming to the servlet method , the way you describe it will work concurrently , but you also need to think about how many users concurrently ? Since for each user , there would be a separate request , there would be some network latency involved for multiple calls. You need to think about all these factors before going ahead with this option

Since you have the code for one user's job , you can define a thread class which has userid as an attribute. In the run() method call the code for a particular user's job.

Now create two threads and set the appropriate userid for each thread and spawn them off.

If the number of users are more , you can look at using Java's Thread Pool Executor .

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going to use a servlet container then it's going to manage multithreading for you. Every servlet request will be executed in a different thread. In that scenario one servlet call would execute on block of code from provided XML in a single threaded manner. If there are several sites declared per block of code they would be visited serially. Other user in the same time may call the same server with other block of code running in parallel with the first one.